# how to log into hidden services

Tags: onion-services

When I go to the hidden wiki page and go to a services site, I can't actually get things done and can't quite figure it out. The problem is that they want a username and password, but how do I register for that? There is no direction for that. Is it a secret word of mouth thing or do I have to search through forums or do I use my stack username and password?

Comment: Could you give an example hidden service that requests login details?

Comment: Since the whole purpose of using Tor is to support the maintenance of your anonymity, even attempting (incorrectly) to use a user name and password from another site sounds like a bad idea. A bad-apple onion-site owner could simply collect your details even if they were never used. Of course, the same thing can happen just as easily on a non-onion site; the difference is that while the bad-apple gets the same information, the threat to you might be different.

Answer (score 1):

Logging in to onionsites works the same way as logging into websites. Namely, it depends on the site. How do you log in to facebook? Well you have to sign up. How do you log in to gmail? Sign up with gmail. Every website has its own way of letter users sign up and log in. The same goes for onionsites. If you want a more specific answer, you need to provide a specific onion address.